# mathjax dosent recognize some data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, mathjax

Trying to debug some mathjax problems in a CI/AngularJS project. 
have run into a problem where this equation is properly parsed as mathjax content:

```
    \[x<6\]
```

but this one is not:

```
    \[0<x<6\]
```

My mathJax config looks so:

```
               MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {
                    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]},
                    processEscapes: true},{TeX: {
                    extensions: ["cancel.js"]
               }});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone gets stuck on this silly one, the right way to go is (notice spacing!):

```
     \[ 0 < x < 6 \]
```

Comment: MathJax does not care about the spacing so there is probably a different reason for the original failure.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks. Could you suggest such a possible reason or where I should find it?

Comment: Hard to say without a sample. Could you put an example on jsfiddle, codepen or something like that?